# How does Teen Titans fit in with the Young Justice continuity?

Tags: dc, continuity, robin, teen-titans, young-justice

Specifically, I am curious about Dick Grayson, as he's the Robin in both shows. The interesting part is thus: Cyborg and Raven from the *Teen Titans* are both founding members of The Justice League, and are similar in age to Robin. Robin in *Young Justice* is a part of the team of sidekicks of The Justice League.

This doesn't make sense to me, seeing that in the first few episodes of *Young Justice*, he is told to be 13, and we know via the sneak peak to his middle school that Robin from YJ is Dick Grayson.

Via a few different places, namely [a Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=teen%20titans%20robin&oq=teen%20titans%20robin&aqs=chrome..69i57j0j69i60l2.4682j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) and [the Wikia page](https://teentitans.fandom.com/wiki/Robin), Robin from *Teen Titans* could be either Dick Grayson, or Tim Drake. What really gets me is the timeline.

If Cyborg being of similar age to Robyn is Dick Grayson in TT, then how (being that Cyborg helped found the JL) can Dick Grayson not only be Robin in YJ, but also be 13 in that.

Now if we take it as Tim Drake (whose predecessor is Dick Grayson) is Robin in TT, then we get an *even bigger* time gap, and time seems to loop on itself, with Tim Drake being younger and at the same time older than Dick Grayson. This leads me to the ultimate question of:

**Where does Teen Titans fit in with Young Justice continuity?**

Comment: They aren't connected at all.

Comment: @PatrickWynne How is that possible given the character sets and comics?

Comment: They take place in different continuities. Your question is similar to asking about the differences between Nolan's Batman and Batman v Superman.

Comment: As far as I know, the *Teen Titans* cartoons of the 2000s have never been supposed to "fit in" with the continuity of any other DC-comics-based TV show that was turning out episodes before, during, or after the *Teen Titans* run. Instead, that show was just doing its own thing, putting a distinctive spin on preexisting character concepts from the comic books. (The same way that the British series *Sherlock* and the American series *Elementary* have nothing to do with one another, even though they both feature a consulting detective named "Sherlock Holmes.")

Comment: @Lorendiac If you have sources for that, it sounds like a great answer!

Comment: In most cases, animated shows do not connect, even if they feature the same characters.  So while the "Dini-verse" shows - Batman:TAS, Superman: TAS and Justice League/ JLUnlimited all take place in the same coherent universe, the other Batman shows like Batman:tB&tB and "The Batman" do not. Tl;dr - Young Justice operates in its own continuity, even though it feature many characters who have appeared on other animated series, including several Teen Titans.

Comment: @VBartilucci Also an excellent answer, should you have sources. XD

Comment: Hard to think of what you'd consider a proper source. It's always been taken as read in comics and animation that shows "don't touch", as most of the time in the past various shows were done by different companies that would rarely cooperate. I don't know if it's something that would be mentioned in an interview or anything since it's the assumed default.

Comment: @VBartilucci Not source as in verified per-se, but more what would make you believe that they don't, and therefore shouldn't in this case as well.

Comment: Well let's see... in past TV shows, series made by different production companies would at the very least feature wildly different character designs, and in many cases adapt the same stories from the comics source, with wildly different details.  the various Fantastic Four shows all used the same villains in wildly different stories. It's been the default, and only exceptions to the rule are usually mentioned, ie the Diniverse.

Comment: Uncomfortably? ;-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Simple Answer?**

There is no simple answer when it comes to DC and continuity.

The comics all have their own separate continuities, while the various TV series' continuity is dependent on the production team.

As @VBartilucci mentioned in his comments; *Young Justice* and the *Teen Titans* show are not part of the same continuity.

More specifically, *Young Justice* is set on [Earth-16](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Earth-16), while *Teen Titans* is a completely [separate continuity](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Teen_Titans_(TV_Series)#Summary).

Additionally, *Batman: The Animated Series*, *Justice League*, *Superman* and the rest of the shows that were produced by the same team, have their own continuity and Multiverse under the [DC Animated Universe](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/DCAU) banner.

Comment: Not to mention all the recent animated DC films, which (naturally) have no continuity relationship with any of the things you mentioned.

Answer (score 4):

*Teen Titans* (2003) and *Young Justice* never existed in the same universe and do not fit together. Both shows use Dick Grayson (Robin) as one of the main protagonists. For *Teen Titans*, this is confirmed in the episode "Fractured" and the appearance of "Larry" (whose real name is Dick Grayson spelt backwards). *Teen Titans* is loosely based off the comic series *The New Teen Titans*. I say loosely because the lineup and characterisations were changed from the comic. *Young Justice* is a next-gen continuation of *Justice League: The Animated Series*. *Teen Titans* and *Young Justice* exist entirely separate from each other and share no overlap, with *Teen Titans Go!* episodes being the exception (but they are created for humor and are not canon content).

When it comes to other characters beyond Dick Grayson, it's a simple explanation. Cyborg *was* a member of the Teen Titans, but after the New-52 reboot, he was aged up, his backstory modified, and he became a founding member of the Justice League. Raven was *never* a member of the Justice League. She has engaged with them and has worked independently, but she always remained a Titans member. In fact, Raven was *the* founding member in the comics and approached Robin rather than the other way around.

For some reason, the writers continue to de-age the Titans members to fit the age of the current Robin. They also tend to recycle story arcs to include the new Robin (see: the Trigon arc, Slade/Terra's arc, etc.). The only character immune to this is Koriand'r/Starfire as she is one of Dick Grayson's love interests and therefore matches him in age. Dick Grayson remains the founding member of the Titans, but all main Robins (Dick, Jason, Tim, and Damian) have spent time at Titans Tower to train in team-building.

In the end, post-New 52, neither series is a part of the main DCU timeline. *Teen Titans* never tied in with other content, like movies or shows, and *Young Justice* now takes place on Earth-16. The latest DCU Animated Original Movies (*Son of Batman*, *Justice League vs. Teen Titans*, *Teen Titans: The Judas Contract*) are the current canon. The Titans members are roughly the same age as Damian Wayne; Dick Grayson is older than all other Titans, bar Kori; and there is no mention of the other *Young Justice* main characters in the animated films, yet.

This is probably more information than necessary, and I know others have posted briefer answers, but I hope this helps clarify the answers given.

Answer (score 3):

The *Teen Titans* show is based in its own universe only taking inspiration from prior DC material. *Young Justice* is a loose continuation of *Justice League/JLU/Batman/Superman: The Animated Series*. Everything that has happened in those shows has already happened in *Young Justice*.

I do not believe DC will officially put *Teen Titans* in *Young Justice* due to the difficulty of merging the continuity. However, they seem to have used the Outsiders team as a *Young Justice* version of the TTs with much inspiration from comic run of TT's line-up. They have a big building (not T-shaped though) based in San Francisco, and operates basically independently from the League. Basically they used the Outsiders' name and small story aspect from original Outsiders, but used *Teen Titans* as the basis of characters and how they interact.

Comment: Your main answer is that _Teen Titans_ is based in its own universe however, if I'm reading it correctly, a lot of your answer then talks about how _Young Justice_ fits in to the rest of the canon material. Do you have any evidence that you could [edit] in that tells us that _Teen Titans_ is in its own universe?

Comment: *Young Justice* is clearly not a loose continuation of the DCAU. Among other things, Zatanna is young in the new show, while in the DCAU she's a contemporary (and former love interest) of Batman. The villains are different in their portrayals between the two shows (Vandal Savage being a prime example). What Mother Boxes are is different. There are no White Martians in the DCAU, and J'onn is the last native Martian, unlike the YJ continuity. So on and so forth.

Answer (score 1):

I believe they are *a little bit* connected because Cyborg started out as a member of the Justice Leaque, then passing down to Teen Titans and back and forth. A post discussing this topic in particular can be found [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/173297/does-cyborg-start-out-as-a-teen-titan-or-as-a-member-of-the-justice-league?rq=1). In the first answer, however, it states that **Cyborg is exclusively a Teen Titans member** but last year in the *Injustice 2* video game, Young Justice and Teen Titans teamed up.

In my honest opinion, Teen Titans and the Justice League are essentially the same, except the former just has teenage members. I guess this was how they became affiliated with Young Justice in the first place.

However, I remember one of the Teen Titans episodes stating how the Teen Titans group formed in the first place. Starfire was captured by a group of dangerous aliens in space, but with her powers and all, she escaped and headed to the nearest planet -- Earth. There, she flew in a city where Robin (the Dick Grayson version) had just moved into since he no longer wanted to work with Batman and wants to instead go solo, fighting crime on his own.

The same kind of thing happens with Beast Boy, where he leaves the superhero team, *Doom Patrol*, and wants to find other superheroes to work with, but at the end of the day, Robin's story does not give reason for him to be part of Young Justice, simply because of Batman.

I guess @SumanRoy's answer explains the concept in the best way.

---

I apologise if I don't fully answer the question, but by answering as I have, I hope to bring forward new details and clean some of the surface.

Answer (score -1):

I assume *Teen Titans* is faaar in the future (though, in the DC and Marvel universes there are a lot of plot holes). Why Batman is there, and young. Dick Grayson is young.

> Dick Grayson, the first Robin later on becomes Nightwing as an adult. The second Robin is Jason Todd, killed brutally by the Joker and Damian, the SON of Batman with the daughter of Ras al Ghul or however is written, is the leader as far as I know, of Teen Titans. He is the last Robin as far as I know, and becomes the leader of the Teen Titans even further into the future.

That’s why I think they have nothing to do. There should be at least 15 years between them, probably more.

Answer (score -1):

I think during the timeskip between season 1 and 2 of YJ Dick Grayson founded the Teen titans. This only makes sense because Beast boy joins the YJ in season two and later founds the outsiders. The time line of TT can definently fit 5 years because that is how long the timeskip was between season 1 and 2 of the YJ is. Which is the biggest reason why Nightwing is the leader of the YJ in season 2. During that time is definently is plausible that Dick founded the TT. Hard to wrap around but It fits perfectly based on the logic. So down below is exactly what the timeline is:

YJ S1 -> TT (entire series/5yrs) ->  YJ S2 (dick becomes NW and is leader of YJ) -> YJ s3 (outsiders)

Comment: Whilst a nice theory do you have anything official to back this up you could [edit] in or is it your own theory?